# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Crypt_RSA' not found

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, phpseclib

I'm using php [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).And i get following error when execute the script

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Crypt_RSA' not found
 in /home/xxxxx/public_html/index.php on line 5
```

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php

include('library/php/Net/SSH2.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->setPassword('891600909v');
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('891600909'));<--This is the pvt key file in home directory in my ubuntu PC-->

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.xxxxx.com');
if (!$ssh->login('xxxxx.com', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('xxxxx.com@xxxxx.com:~$');
$ssh->write("ls -la\n");
echo $ssh->read('xxxxx.com@xxxxx.com:~$');

?>
```

How could i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also include the RSA.php file for the Crypt_RSA class.

Add this underneath your other include (assuming you have this file downloaded):

```
include('library/php/Crypt/RSA.php');
```

Comment: Now says require_once(Math/BigInteger.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxxxx/public_html/library/php/Crypt/RSA.php on line 465

Comment: Make sure you have the whole package downloaded there and the directory structure remains untouched from the ZIP.

Comment: what file should i include into the $key->loadKey(file_get_contents('891600909')); ???

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what Ryan Kempt said make sure your include_path is set appropriately. eg.

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

include('Net/SSH2.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either install phpseclib with pear OR get them from the site

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/pear.htm

Manually download each of the classes you wanted and include them in your main project.

Answer (score 0):

In the current versions of phpseclib, the class `Crypt_RSA` is not existing anymore.
You create it this way:

```
$rsa = \phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA::load("...");
```

or

```
$rsa = \phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA::createKey();
```